# Можно ли в SQL запросе, обновить структуру таблицы в которой есть данные?

Tags: mysql

Например есть два сервера **dev** и **prod** и таблица в БД со множеством строк.

Есть необходимость менять свойства полей, какие-то удалить, а какие-то добавить.

Задача в том, чтобы с **dev** экспортировать структуру таблицы (это будет **sql** файл) и применить новую структуру на **prode**.

Чтобы это сделать, можно ли ограничиться какой-то простой процедурой импорта/экспорта или нужно будет писать специальный скрипт на сервере или последовательность **SQL**-запросов?

Comment: А миграции составить нельзя? Тогда можно было бы хранить где-нибудь текущую миграцию и выполнять только новые. Как вариант - можно создать пустую базу требуемой структуры и вставить туда нужные данные из старой базы, а потом поменять базы местами

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется что вы что делаете не правильно, сама идея экспортировать с dev и  импортировать на prod это уже странно. люди придумали же миграции давным давно. Но если вам сильно нужно, то  насколько я помню для MySql есть mysql workbench или dbforge  умеет сравнивать 2 структуры из разных баз и делать diff данных с уже с общим merge результатом.